# Can't remove item from list in C#

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

In the inventory for my game I want to delete an item if you drop it. This only works in a foreach loop like this:

```
public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

public void DeleteItem(Item itemToRemove)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        items.Remove(itemToRemove);
    }
}
```

but then I get this error:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

When I just try this:

```
public void DeleteItem(Item itemToRemove)
{
        items.Remove(itemToRemove);
}
```

nothing happens. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You don’t need a loop. Just remove it if it exists in the list. I also don’t see any difference in the two snippets posted

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen sorry, I forgot to change the 2nd code. without a loop it doesn't work for some reason, do you know why?, do you maybe know how to fix this error: enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: Are you sure, that the item does exist only one time in your list?  Check, whether the remove method returns true or false or check items.Count() before and after remove.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was another script attached which directly added the item back if I dropped the gun, so that was the error.

Answer (score 6):

To remove an item from a list, it is sufficient to do this:

```cs
public void DeleteItem(Item itemToRemove) 
{
  items.Remove(itemToRemove);
}
```

You don't actually have to loop through the list. If nothing seems to happen, check the return value of [Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=netframework-4.8). It returns `true` if the item was removed, or `false` if the item couldn't be found in the list.

Regarding the error message you're getting: you must not modify a list by adding/removing items while you're enumerating through it. This will change the length of the list, and throws off the enumeration, so it is not allowed.

Comment: I already tried this and nothing happened, do you maybe know how to fix the error, because my script works, only the error is very annoying. Oh, and how do you check the return value?

Comment: Do check the return value of `items.Remove`. If it's `false`, the item wasn't in the list. Also, be sure you're actually trying to remove the same instance of an item, rather than a new instance which happens to have the same values.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I forgot about another script, so that's why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

That error indicates that you are changing a collection at the same time as you are looping over it. This is unsafe because once the collection changes the iterator state may no longer be valid. For example, the iterator might be pointing to index 3 in a list, but if you remove item 0 (shifting everything else back) then you’d end up skipping ahead. Throwing this error avoids this sort of subtle bug by making it obvious.

In this particular case, you shouldn’t need a loop: just remove the item.

If you want to do bulk removal, consider methods like RemoveAll.

Another option is to loop over a copy of the list, which leaves you free to modify it. For example, you could loop over items.ToArray().